# Trigonometric identity: Sum of the squares of sine, cosine and tangent.

Tags: trigonometry

One has that the sum of the squares of the functions sine, cosine and tangent satisfy

$$ \sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) + \tan^2(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \tan (x)$$

Does this have any nice interpretation or meaning, or is it simply just a complicated way of writing $1 + \tan^2(x)$ without given any insight?

Comment: I would say the second statement of yours is true.

Comment: Well, you could see this as meaning that the rate of change of the tangent function is equal to the square of the diagonal of the parallelepiped with sides $\sin, \cos, \tan$. *Why* (geometrically) that holds is not clear to me, however.

Answer (score 1):

It's just an equality as both the sides are equal to $\sec^2 x$ $$LHS=\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x+\tan^2 x=(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)+\tan^2x=1+\tan^2x=\sec^2x$$
$$RHS=\frac{d}{dx}(\tan x)=\sec^2x$$
so briefly, $$LHS=RHS=\sec^2 x$$ 
in other words, it just a way rather a complicated way of writing $\sec^2 x$

Comment: OP says "*Does this have any nice interpretation or meaning*"? The answer primarily should be **yes** or **no**, and if yes, then what it is? From the question, it is clear that he did not asked about this approach, he already knows this.